# how to return one of two types of custom table view cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parsing

I have a table view controller with two different prototype cells: one for just a story to be posted and the other for a picture with or with out a story. After much research I have found that I have to use a switch or an if statement in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject*)object
```

to achieve this. The way I want to Filter this is by using a key on parse that either contains Picture or story for each post. I have put this code together but cant seem to make it work any help will be greatly appreciated and I can clarify anything that doesn't make sense.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    PFObject *filter = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Post"];
    NSString *cellFilter = [filter objectForKey:@"cellFilter"];

    if (cellFilter == @"picture") {
        static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"pictureCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        //assign the data to the labels and image view
        return cell;
    }else{
        static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"storyCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        //assign the data to the labels
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==`, instead use `isEqualToString:`. What issues are you seeing specifically?

Comment: What are your results with the current code?

Comment: You are realizing that you will get the exact same flow through the method body for each cell because you completely ignore any information regarding the current indexPath or the passed in PFObject. Either you always return a pictureCell OR always return a storyCell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something more like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PFObject *filter = [PFObject filterForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellFilter = [filter objectForKey:@"cellFilter"];

    /* Insert code for returning cell based on cellFilter */
}
```

If you don't implement the method from the UITableViewDataSource protocol then it will never get called. Adding your own "object" parameter means that it's completely unknown to the table view.

Additionally, you need to implement a method (filterForRowAtIndexPath in above example) that will return a different filter depending on the table row that's being queried.

Comment: i'm a little confused, how would i set up the 'filterForRowAtIndexPath'?